# PMML 4.4 xml parse exception

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, pmml

Hi one of my project requirement is to create a PMML manually . Till 4.2 version it was working fine now im trying to do the same using 4.4 version but it is giving me the below error.

> Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"PMML"). Expected elements are <{https://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_4}AR>......

This is my sample code

```
String pmmlString="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><PMML xmlns=\"http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_4\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" version=\"4.4\"></PMML>";
    PMML pmml = null;
    XMLStreamReader xsr = null;
    try {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(PMML.class);
        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, false);
        xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, false);
        xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, false);
        xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(pmmlString.getBytes()));

        pmml = (PMML) u.unmarshal(xsr);

    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (xsr != null) {
            try {
                xsr.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Im following the exact same structure as mentioned in https://dmg.org/pmml/v4-4/GeneralStructure.html

Comment: If a validator says that your XML is invalid then it probably is, and we're not going to be able to explain why it's invalid unless you show us the XML. My guess would be that it's a namespace issue, but without seeing it, that can only be a wild guess.

Comment: @MichaelKay i downloaded the pmml4.4.xsd from https://dmg.org/pmml/pmml-v4-4.html created the java files(jar) from it . The first line in the code has a sample xml as string -->pmmlString . I think the issue is with the generated java classes but how to find out. There is no option to share the jar file as well.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you any further. It definitely looks like a namespace problem: the error message says it found a PMML element in no namespace when it was looking for a PMML element in the namespace `http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_4\`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i convert the xsd to java jaxb creates the package-info.java which looks like below `@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "https://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_4", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) package com.fico.carbon.pmml;`

once i remove the above annotation it started working

Comment: This is a workaround, not a correct fix.

Answer (score 0):

In short, your PMML string refers to the `http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_4` XML namespace URI (**HTTP** protocol), but your PMML XSD file refers to the `https://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_4` one (**HTTPS** protocol). These two are different XML namespace URIs, hence your parser is correct that the PMML string does not comply with PMML XSD.

It appears that DMG.org migrated their website from HTTP to HTTPS sometimes in early summer 2022. They must have done this by performing a brute force string replace on all their site content too - including the attachment files (such as PMML XSD files).

Obviously, this string replace was performed incorrectly, because it is not correct to change XML namespace URI prefixes like that. This bug has been reported to DMG.org as [issue 274](http://mantis.dmg.org/view.php?id=274), but there is no reaction/feedback to it.

TLDR: Your PMML string is correct. You need to manually edit the newly downloaded PMML XSD file, and change the PMML namespace URI from HTTPS back to HTTP. Then it will work (as it worked for years and years).

Comment: See also https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-model/issues/38